# Call default apps in android to view different documents

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am developing a Cordova Android and iOS application. I am downloading multiple format of documents in my app like PDF and HTML.
I need to open these document from my app. Is there any way to call a default PDF application or other application that support the format of the document from my Cordova application?

I know that the final resolution is to write my own implementation to read the documents using 3rd party libraries.

UPDATE:(Another plugin option) 
IF you have similar requirement. Have a look at
https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2 
This plugin supports both iOS and Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to try out with external **FileOpener** library then i think it will works.

Try this link :- https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: The fact that its a Cordova Plugin helps a lot. Will try it out on both Android and iOS to see if serves my purpose. Thanks for the help

Comment: it worked but had a requirement with iOS as well. The fileopener only supports android at the moment. https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2 supports both iOS and Android

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in Android as follows:

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(fileUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you are handling multiple file types, use [Intent.setType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType%28java.lang.String%29)

You can use [MimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html#getMimeTypeFromExtension%28java.lang.String%29) to get the type you need to set in the Intent.

Comment: seems to be a good option but specific to Android. Will give it a try if @Born-to-win's method does not work. Thanks for the help though :D

Comment: Yeah I figured this was for Cordova after posting the answer :)